# How to split a name string in C?

Tags: c, string

What is the standard way to split a string of the form "command Name_1 Name_2 Name_3..." in C? (It is unknown how many names follow after the command.) I tried to use "strtok", but this splits the names into separate parts.

So to be clear: I want to obtain the string "Name_1 Name_2 Name_3...".

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


int main()
{
  char string[] = "command Name_1 Name_2 Name_3";
  char* token_1 = strtok(string, " ");
  char* token_2 = strtok(NULL, " ");
  printf("token_1 = %s\n", token_1);
  printf("token_2 = %s\n", token_2);

  return 0;
}
```

EDIT: I clarified my question by adding a minimum working example.

Comment: What *have* you tried? Please create a [mre] and show it.

Comment: @Frederik: I want to split the string into two strings, where token_1 contains "command" and tokend_2 "Name_1 Name_2 Name_3..."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`strtok` also returns when the end of the string is reached, as if a NUL was in the character list, so just pass an empty character list.

Replace

```c
char* token_1 = strtok(string, " ");   // First token is ended by space or NUL
char* token_2 = strtok(NULL, " ");     // Next token is ended by space or NUL
```

with

```c
char* token_1 = strtok(string, " ");   // First token is ended by space or NUL
char* token_2 = strtok(NULL, "");      // Next token is ended by NUL
```

**Warning**: If there are more than one spaces after the first token, all but the first will be part of the second token.

Answer (score 2):

The `strtok` function searches for the first character which is **not** contained in delim, then searches from that point on for the first character that **is** contained in delim.

To get the rest of the string you can call:

```
char* token_2 = strtok(NULL, "");
```

Answer (score 0):

> What is the standard way to split a string of the form "command Name_1 Name_2 Name_3..." in C? (It is unknown how many names follow after the command.) I tried to use "strtok", but this splits the names into separate parts.

I don't full understand your last question's sentence:

> So to be clear: I want to obtain the string "Name_1 Name_2 Name_3...".

You depart from `"Name_1 Name_2 Name_3..."`, and you want to obtain `"Name_1 Name_2 Name_3..."` ???  I'll try to understand, by your examples, that what you try to obtain is the following thing:

```
{"Name_1", "Name_2", "Name_3", ..., NULL};
```

instead, as if you wanted to call `execl(2)` with an array of strings.

Well, the shell today has to distinguish about quoted strings and conserve the spaces inside them, making your problem a bit more complex.  But despite of that, I'll put some light on how to solve what I interpret about your problem (which is not to say much, once read your last paragraph).

The conversion of a string into an array of words, has been done historically with the use of `strtok()` function in some way more or less like the following:

```
char **array_of_strings = NULL;
size_t array_of_strings_len = 0,
       array_of_strings_cap = 0;
for (char *s = strtok(input_string, " \t\n");
        s;
        s = strtok(NULL, " \t\n"); // <-- this was the contents of IFS env var.
{
    if (array_of_strings_len == array_of_strings_cap) {
        array_of_strings_cap += INCREMENT; /* put some value like 10 on INCREMENT */
        array_of_strings = realloc(array_of_strings,
                                   array_of_strings_cap 
                                       * sizeof *array_of_strings);
    }
    array_of_strings[array_of_strings_len++] = s;
}
/* put a NULL at the end */
if (array_of_strings_len == array_of_strings_cap) {
    array_of_strings_cap++; /* only add one, in this case, as we are ending */
    array_of_strings = realloc(array_of_strings,
                               array_of_strings_cap 
                                   * sizeof *array_of_strings);
}
array_of_strings[array_of_strings_len] = NULL;
for (int i = 0; array_of_strings[i]; i++) {
    printf("array_of_strings[%d] == \"%s\"\n", i, array_of_strings[i]);
}
```

This requires that you conserve the original string untouched, as the pointers point into the `strtok()` modified string. If that is not possible, then you can, at start

```
input_string = strdup(input_string); // allocate space and dup the original string.
```

so you can work with the original buffer pointed by `input_string`.  Then you must also take care of the contents of `input_string` in addition to `array_of_strings`  (both will need to be `free()`d instead of only `array_of_strings`)

**Note:**  this code has not been tested, as it is only a snippet.  But you will not have trouble on working on a suitable complete code and correct any mistake I could do.  Thanks for your understanding.